# gradle dependencyUpdates failure

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I have "installed" or included ben manes - gradle versions plugin:

https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

The code below is the build.gradle (Project: rewards)

apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.20.0"
    }
}
```

When I try to run the following gradle Task: **gradle dependencyUpdates**.

I get the following :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 What went wrong:
Task 'gradle' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are: 'bundle'.
 Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 0s
11:23:53: Tasks execution finished 'gradle dependencyUpdates'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, I realised that the task that I need to run should not have the word gradle in front. The command line instruction should just be **dependencyUpdates**. Then click on okay and it will export the report.

[image]